# SSRS, combine row and column groups , is it possible

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2012

I have this simple report and I tried to use both row and column groups, and I still getting that value on rank column in separate lines (1 line per each rank). Can I display that  values (77, 22, 44) on single line somehow ? So I don't need those line marked with red crosses.
Note that Rank for PR for each Loc is diff so I display only Rank, don't care about product, it's OK, I display only rank and count for rank. I finished doing pivot in sql, but would like to try do this in rdl.[image]
I also include sample ds here
Tx Mario

```
select 'EUROPE' LOC_NAME, '70' PR_CODE, 'Product 700 for man' PR, 'Local'  RACE, '96'  CC, '1' RK   union
select 'EUROPE' LOC_NAME, '400' PR_CODE, 'Product 400' PR, 'Local'  RACE, '116'  CC, '2' RK union
select 'EUROPE' LOC_NAME, '70' PR_CODE, 'Product 700 for man' PR, 'Unknown'  RACE, '37'  CC, '1' RK union
select 'EUROPE' LOC_NAME, '200' PR_CODE, 'Product 200 for women' PR, 'Unknown'  RACE, '13'  CC, '3' RK  union
select 'EUROPE' LOC_NAME, '200' PR_CODE, 'Product 200 for women' PR, 'Local'      RACE, '74'  CC, '3' RK    union
select 'EUROPE' LOC_NAME, '400' PR_CODE, 'Product 400' PR, 'Unknown'  RACE, '25'  CC, '2' RK    union
select 'ASIA' LOC_NAME, '70' PR_CODE, 'Product 700 for man' PR, 'Local'  RACE, '22'  CC, '2' RK union
select 'ASIA' LOC_NAME, '550' PR_CODE, 'Product 550 ASIA ' PR, 'Local'  RACE, '44'  CC, '3' RK  union
select 'ASIA' LOC_NAME, '70' PR_CODE, 'Product 700 for man' PR, 'Unknown'  RACE, '55'  CC, '2' RK   union
select 'ASIA' LOC_NAME, '200' PR_CODE, 'Product 200 for women' PR, 'Unknown'  RACE, '66'  CC, '1' RK    union
select 'ASIA' LOC_NAME, '200' PR_CODE, 'Product 200 for women' PR, 'Local'  RACE, '77'  CC, '1' RK  union
select 'ASIA' LOC_NAME, '550' PR_CODE, 'Product 550 ASIA ' PR, 'Unknown'  RACE, '33'  CC, '3' RK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is better suited for a matrix. I did this by using a matrix component instead, taking your dataset with the following data arrangement:
[image]

And in the preview it generates the following matrix:

[image]

Comment: Mucho Gracias Alejandro