# is it possible to get multiple subrows for one row and 2 columns SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I would need to do a report looking like this :
[image]

For any given "person" there is a single firstname, last name and age, but I can have as many surnames as the user sees fit. Each surname has a corresponding "apparition surname order". The column order is really important, but if that helps I could try to reorganise them.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594187/ssrs-combine-row-and-column-groups-is-it-possible) but it doesn't seem to be quite the result I'm looking for.
Additionally each person has a unique id, but I don't want it to be displayed.

I've tried to use tablix inside a tablix and a matrix but I'm kinda lost to be honest.
I would like to know if that is at least possible to achieve ?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902255/unwanted-space-appearing-under-nested-table-in-ssrs-report/66950780#66950780

Comment: If you can move the Age by the Lastname, it's relatively easy with one level of grouping by ID with the name and then detail group for the Surname.